# Inno Setup uninstaller always freeze after execute Windows Service Manager to remove a service

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation, sc.exe

I'm trying to remove a service of my program when the uninstall is executed, I'm using the `UninstallRun` section, the problem happens after Inno execute the service control process, that hangs my uninstaller, the code:

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "delete myservice"; Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser
```

Inno Version: 6

OS: Windows 10 22H2 x64

Can anybody help me?